# Alternative syntax for "for loop" in python

Tags: python, for-loop, kaggle

When learning python basics from Kaggle scripts i encountered such code:

```
NL_1 = [elem.split("\n") for elem in Name_list]
```

Where Name_list is list of character objects - names of people in titanic dataset.

I know what does it do, but still i feel quite lost with this syntax. My question is: **what is the name of this concept** and optionally **what else should i learn to understand it**.

Comment: This was actually a simple question, and should have been answered. He/she asked : name of the concept. It's a bit difficult to search for an answer when you don't even know what to search for.

Comment: @imranal I don't think closing it as a duplicate necessarily means "you should have searched for this". Now, there is a link to the answer with detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks for support. Still - i got an answer, even if it was provided in quite a hard way. And thats true, it is hard to find answer when you do not know what to look for.